# How to embed vlc in my windows form application with c#

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to make an app that can control my IP cameras.VLC media player can do this but I don't know how to embed it in my app to add features to it like capture a picture.What should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The VideoLAN Wiki has links about the [.Net Interface to VLC](http://wiki.videolan.org/.Net_Interface_to_VLC) as well as [C# bindings](http://wiki.videolan.org/C_Sharp) for libvlc, which is the underlying library of VLC.

You will find there several projects such as [VLCdotNet](http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/) which seems to be something that you can use.

You can also get into the .Net Interface to VLC by looking at the sources of the [DMediaPlayer on CodePlex](http://dmediaplayer.codeplex.com/).