# Embedding a VLC player into a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, vlc

I am interested in embedding a VLC player into a WPF application. It is to be used as a quality control tool where the user can watch a movie, pause, and move to different frames in order to get a good idea of how the movie looks. Most of these will be MP4 files, but with a few .MOV files. (Hence the need for VLC) Does anybody know where to start? I have seen the activex page and am thinking that would be the best way to go. Does anyone have any insights or a link to a good guide?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to use the [VLC ActiveX plugin](http://wiki.videolan.org/ActiveX).

See also:

- [Using the VLC ActiveX control in WPF](http://zahidakbar.wordpress.com/2011/06/27/using-the-vlc-activex-control-in-wpf/)
- [How to embed vlc in my windows form application with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645743/how-to-embed-vlc-in-my-windows-form-application-with-c-sharp)
- [Walkthrough: Hosting an ActiveX Control in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742735.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [VideoLan DotNet](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/), they have VLC controls for WPF and Winforms.

[Here](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/wiki) is the tutorial.

Comment: 4 years later, not production ready.